# AngularJS using ng-repeat twice in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This problem comes from the AngularJS.org tutorial
We have created a table with this code:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>row number</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"><td>{{i+1}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

That gives us a 1 row table.
The extra point challenge is to make an 8x8 table using an additional ng-repeat. I have tried several times in different ways to create 7 additional columns by adding an ng-repeat but I almost always end up with a 9th row of code instead of data.

BTW, there are actually no points earned; I just want the knowledge.

Comment: You get a row with one <tr>.
You get a column with <td>.
So you need to loop 8 tr's and 8 td's in your case

Comment: I understand but how? I don't have the proper syntax that maintains the row number correctly.

Comment: Well you see your code now produces 8 <tr>s each <tr> only contains one <td>. you want it to have 8x8 just use 2 ng-repeat-- one on tr and another on td. Solution from @Chrillewoodz should do.

Answer (score 2):

This would create an 8x8 table using nested `ng-repeat`:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
    <td ng-repeat="j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{j}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The new output:from that does not properly number the rows. All row numbers are now "0" where they used to be 1 through 8.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem still exists - here are two variants of filling the table - row by row and column by column (from 1 to 8). Use nested directive `ng-repeat` in `<tr>` and `<td>`

Row-by-row:

```
<table>
    <tr><th colspan="8">Row number</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat = "i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
        <td ng-repeat = "j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{j+1}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Column-by-column:

```
<table>
  <tr><th colspan="8">Row number</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat = "i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
        <td ng-repeat = "j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{i+1}}</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```